# Rectangular Overlays appearing only after dragging the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a lot of markers and I m using markerClusterer to display them on the map.Additionally on click of a checkbox I need to display a rectangular overlay (title) near all these markers.

I have written 2 functions as follows for creating the overlay and deleting it.

```
function createLabel(posi,name){
 posicion = etiquetaNombre.length;
 etiquetaNombre[posicion] = name;
 var label = new Label({
        position:posi,
         map: map,
         text:name
        });
rectangleNombre[posicion]=label;
rectangleNombre[posicion].setMap(map);
console.log("add: etiquetaNombre",etiquetaNombre);
myfun();    
 }
 function deletelabel(name){
 for(var i = 0; i < etiquetaNombre.length; i++){
        if(etiquetaNombre[i] == name){
            rectangleNombre[i].setMap(null);
            rectangleNombre.splice(i, 1);           
            etiquetaNombre.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
console.log("delete marker"+name);
console.log("delete: etiquetaNombre",etiquetaNombre);
myfun();    
 }
```

I m invoking the createLabel function as follows:

```
          var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
          new google.maps.Size(24, 32));
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100);
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
          var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
              data.photos[i].longitude);
          var div=document.createElement('div');    

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          draggable: false,
          map: map,
          title:"marker"+i
         });
        posi=marker.position;
            name=marker.title;
        createLabel(latLng,name);

        markers.push(marker);
         }
     markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Since I am using markerClusterer I had to customize it for my above requirement.I had done it as below.

```
Cluster.prototype.addMarker = function(marker) {
/// some lines
 if (len < this.minClusterSize_ && marker.getMap() != this.map_) {
    // Min cluster size not reached so show the marker.
    marker.setMap(this.map_);
    posi=marker.position;
    name=marker.title;                
    createLabel(posi,name);
  }

  if (len == this.minClusterSize_) {
    // Hide the markers that were showing.
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

      this.markers_[i].setMap(null);
      name=this.markers_[i].title;
      deletelabel(name);
    }
  }

  if (len >= this.minClusterSize_) {

    marker.setMap(null);
    name=marker.title;
    deletelabel(name);
  }

  this.updateIcon();
  return true;
};
```

The myfun() is called on click of check box is as below.

```
 function myfun(){
var element=document.getElementById('id1');
if(element.checked){
for(var i = 0; i < etiquetaNombre.length; i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('normal-'+etiquetaNombre[i]);
        if(div!=null){
        div.style.display = "";
        }
    }
console.log("in my fun element checked",etiquetaNombre);
}
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
  if(element.checked){
        for(var i=0; i<etiquetaNombre.length; i++){
        var div = document.getElementById('normal-'+etiquetaNombre[i]);
        if(div!=null){
        div.style.display = "";
        }
    } 
}

});
}
```

The problem which I m facing here is that on zooming when the clustered markers are disintegrated the rectangular overlays do not appear for them.But on simply dragging the map it appears.Can anybody guide what I m doing wrong here.

[Edited]

```
function createLabel(xCenter , yCenter, nombre,banderaPersonalizada){

        posicion = etiquetaNombre.length;

        etiquetaNombre[posicion] = nombre;  

        var RectangleBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(yCenter,xCenter), new google.maps.LatLng((yCenter+1),(xCenter+1)));   

        rectangleNombre[posicion] = new RectangleNombre(RectangleBounds);   

        rectangleNombre[posicion].setMap(map);


}


function RectangleNombre(bounds, opt_weight, opt_color) {
   this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.weight_ = opt_weight || 2;
    this.color_ = opt_color || "#888888";
}
RectangleNombre.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

RectangleNombre.prototype.onAdd = function(map) {

    var idDiv = "normal-"+etiquetaNombre[posicion];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = idDiv;
    div.innerHTML = '<span style=" color:blue; font-family:arial; font-size:7.5pt;    font-weight:900" > '+etiquetaNombre[posicion]+'</span>';
    div.style.position = "absolute";
   console.log("banderaCheckEtiqueta"+banderaCheckEtiqueta);
    if(banderaCheckEtiqueta){

        div.style.display = "";
    } else {

        div.style.display = "none";
    }


    this.getPanes().mapPane.appendChild(div);
    this.map_ = map;
    this.div_ = div;

 }


RectangleNombre.prototype.draw = function() {
    var proj = this.getProjection();
    var c1 = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());

    var c2 = proj.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    this.div_.style.width = "0px";

    this.div_.style.height = "0px";

    this.div_.style.left = c1.x - 12;
    this.div_.style.top = c1.y + 2;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Hi I was able to rectify the issue of overlays disappearing when the map is dragged.But ,the toggle function is not working now.It is giving "div is null" error in the firebug console.I understand that it is because of the div styling which is done in .onAdd function .But I have no idea how to rectify it.Can you please throw some insight into it.Sorry,I m not able to create a fiddle.

Comment: `Sorry,I m not able to create a fiddle.` - makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I m sorry.I have never created a fiddle before.I had tried to create one using http://jsfiddle.net/ but couldnt get the output. I understand that it would be difficult to help.Thanks anyway